# Multipole expansion along a ring

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics

I'm supposed to calculate the behavior of the electrostatic potential $V$ at large distances $|r| \gg a$ for the following linear charge density along a ring of radius $a$:

$$\rho(r,\psi, z) = \frac{q}{2\pi a}\cos(n\psi )\delta(z)\delta(r-a)$$

where $n=0,1,2,....$

**Question 1**: what is that $n$ inside the cosine term for? Am i supposed to just plug numbers in? e.g. for the monoterm, use different $n$ numbers?

**Question 2**: the dirac delta term $\delta z$ requires $z=0$ otherwise the charge density is $0$? So I'm supposed to only integrate the $x,y$ plane, is that correct? And this brrings me back to question 1, since i'm integrating from $0$ to $2\pi$ on the $\theta$ term, the whole thing is $0$? What am i doing or thinking wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> Question 1: what is that $n$  inside the cosine term for?
> Am i supposed to just plug numbers in?
> e.g. for the monoterm, use different $n$ numbers?

Just visualize how the positive and negative charges
are distributed along the ring for different $n$.
For example:

- If $n=0$, then the ring is positively charged everywhere.
- If $n=1$, then one half of the ring ($\psi$ between $-90°$ and $90°$) is positively charged,
  and the other half ($\psi$ between $90°$ and $270°$) is negatively charged.
- ...

You are supposed to find the potential $V(\vec{r})$ for a general $n$.

> Question 2: the dirac delta term $\delta(z)$ requires $z=0$
> otherwise the charge density is $0$?
> So I'm supposed to only integrate the $x,y$ plane, is that correct?
> And this brrings me back to question 1, since i'm integrating from $0$ to $2\pi$
> on the $\theta$ term, the whole thing is $0$ ?
> What am i doing or thinking wrong?

May be you misunderstood something.
You are supposed to calculate the potential
$$V(\vec{r})=\int \frac{\rho(\vec{r}')}{4\pi\epsilon_0|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|}d^3r'$$
at any point $\vec{r}$.
Your conclusion that $V(\vec{r})$ would be always zero, is not correct.
The whole integral will be $0$ for points $\vec{r}$ on the $z$-axis,
but elsewhere the integral will turn out to be non-zero.

Comment: "The whole integral will be 0 for points on the z-axis" — except for $n = 0$.

Comment: More generally, the way to think about why the integral doesn't necessarily vanish is that the parts of the ring with positive charge might be closer to a particular point than the parts with negative charge;  and so the positive contributions to the integral would be greater in magnitude than the negative contributions.

Comment: @Thomasfritsch Thanks for the answer, i now understand the first part, however the second part im still confused, actually im supposed to use multipole expansion, but the integral looks similar anyway i need to integrate this charge density but the dirac delta function term $\delta z$ requires that $z = 0$ otherwise the integral is 0? no?